# Intercepting all custom classes in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, aop

I would like to monitor which of MY classes were accessed during Grails app execution. For this purpose I’m thinking of adding logging into ‘before method invocation’ joint to all custom classes and then inspecting log files.
What is the slickest way of adding such intercepting logic without modifying existing classes?

Metaprogramming/AOP?

Comment: A solution cold be to use the groovy [invokeMethod and getProperty](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty) feature.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10956841/6509

Comment: @Fabiano But this implies modifying existing code (implementing/overriding). I want the logic to be externalized and to be bound to all my classes at a time.

Comment: You can use expandoMetaclass to add invokeMethod and getPropery to you custom classes at the bootstrap of grails without touch che class implementation. [take a look here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass+-+GroovyObject+Methods)

Comment: Interesting approach, but this will require loading all available classes eagerly at start time. I think my JVM won’t be happy :) I’ve got a really fat app...

Comment: I you don't want to do it runtime I think the only alternative is using [global AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Global+AST+Transformations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spring AOP.

To intercept any methods on any classes you want, add this to the bean declarations in resources.groovy:

```
xmlns aop: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" //[1]

aop {
    config {
        pointcut(id: "interceptorPointcut", expression: "execution(* my.basepkg..*(..))") //[2]
        advisor('pointcut-ref': "interceptorPointcut", 'advice-ref': "myInterceptor") //[3]
    }
}

myInterceptor(org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleTraceInterceptor) { //[4]
   loggerName = "myTracer"
}
```

[1] brings in the namespace and schema in for the Spring AOP to use in bean builder

[2] method signature pattern. This one will match any method in any class in my.basepkg or subpackage

[3] binding pointcut and advice

[4] advice bean declaration along with overriding loggerName that will be used to log the interceptor's messages. Add to Config.groovy something like this:

```
appenders {
    rollingFile maxBackupIndex: 5, maxFileSize: '100KB', name: 'fileTracer', file: 'methodtrace.log', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%m%n")
}
trace additivity: false, fileTracer: 'myTracer'
```

SimpleInterceptor is a standard Spring’s interceptor, which logs messages on every method enter/exit/exception. You can use it or another one from org.springframework.aop.interceptor package, or write your own (just extend AbstractTraceInterceptor, it’s simple).

Comment: Sorry you had to answer that one on your own, but I was quite interested in this question.